# Changing ForeignKey doesn't affect parent in Django

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

*I'm on DJANGO 1.5.1 with PostgreSQL 9.3*

I have a UserProfile like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('MALE', _('Male')), ('FEMALE', _('Female')),
    USER_TYPE = (('USER', _('User')), ('SPECIAL', _('Special')))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=13,
                              default='MALE',
                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                              verbose_name=_('gender'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            default='USER',
                            choices=USER_TYPE,
                            verbose_name=_('type'))
```

And a House model:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**When I try to modify the house owner I can't get the infos back from the House queryset:**

I make some modifications on my owner:

```
user.get_profile().type = 'SPECIAL'
user.save()
```

Then I assign owner to my house:

```
house.owner = user
house.save()
```

When I try to get infos back, 'SPECIAL' is not showing up but initial value:

```
house.objects.get(owner=user).owner.get_profile().type 
'USER'
```

If I want to make changes effectives I have to do:

```
house_profile = house.objects.get(owner=user).owner.get_profile()
house_profile.type = 'SPECIAL'
house_profile.save()
```

Why when I change my owner profile it doesn't reflect on my house model ?
This is the same User id, if I change my user infos, it should propagate to all related models, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make changes in a related model, you have to save the object of that model so that changes can be reflected.

```
user_profile = user.get_profile()
user_profile.type = 'SPECIAL'
user_profile.save()
```

You tried:

```
house_profile = house.objects.get(owner=user).owner.get_profile()
house_profile.type = 'SPECIAL'
house_profile.save()
```

This is working because here house_profile is actually a object of user_profile.

Comment: This seems logic, I did not saw that. Thanks!